# Is there an equivalent of a "beforeHandler" for spring 4?

Tags: spring

I have a controller with a requestmapping..

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private static final String template = "Hello there, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public @ResponseBody String hello() {

                      return "Hello";
    }
}
```

How can I make it such that everytime a user goes to a RequestMapping, or whichever url, some other method is called to println to the console the URL the user is at before it actually enters the method "hello"?

I would like to use this method to ensure users have proper credentials in the future. I see there are @PreAuthorize annotation, but there doesnt seem to be a method associated with it that I can write my own logic, i.e. do a simple println to the console with the current URL the user is at.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options.

With Spring, you can implement and register a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) and implement its `preHandle` method to log the request URL, which you can reconstruct with the various `HttpServletRequest` methods.

With pure servlet-api, you can implement and register your own [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which logs the request URL and then continues the chain, with `doFilter(..)`.

You can also use AOP, advise all your `@RequestMapping` annotated methods with a `@Before` advice that logs the URL.

Comment: @Rolando A good example of? For `Filter`, you can annotate the class with `@WebFilter` (with appropriate attributes). With `HandlerInterceptor`, you can use the `@Configuration` class with [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addInterceptors-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry-). For the AOP solution, go through the Spring documentation on AOP. You don't need any XML.